# React Native: Re-render component when multiple styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm faced with a problem: when array of styles passed through props to some component, it re-renders but styles do not change.

I can use shouldComponentUpdate in React.Component, but in my case it's better to use PureComponent.

What can be done about this?

Example:

```
<StyledComponent style={[styles.styleOne, styles.styleTwo]} />
```

StyledComponent:

```
export default class StyledComponent extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    return <View style={this.props.style} />
  }
}
```

PureComponent does not compare an array of styles and re-render StyledComponent

Comment: could you share your source code.

Comment: @SDushan Please see above :)